# How to change the watchdog timer in linux embedded

Tags: linux, arm, embedded-linux, watchdog

I have to use the linux watchdog driver (/dev/watchdog). It works great, I write an character like this:

```
 echo 1 > /dev/watchdog
```

And the watchdog start and after an about 1 minute, the system reboot.

The question is, how can I change the timeout? I have to change the time interval in the driver?

Comment: Most of the watchdog drivers take timeout interval as module_params. Change it while inserting watchdog driver or you can use ioclts(if implemented) to change the timeout value. For that you need to write a simple c program.

Comment: For specific answer, provide the name of your watchdog driver. check it in `lsmod`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Unfortunatelly when I type lsmod it show nothing

Comment: Try looking inside `/sys/devices/platform`. For tegra watchdog device, I get `/sys/devices/platform/tegra_wdt/` directory. From that you can identify the driver mapped to that device.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [Linux documentation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt).  The standard method of changing the *timeout* from user space is to use an `ioctl()`.

```
int timeout = 45;                        /* a time in seconds */
int fd;
fd = open("/dev/watchdog");
ioctl(fd, WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT, &timeout);   /* Send time request to the driver. */
```

Each watchdog device may have an upper (and possibly lower) limit on that the hardware supports, so you can not set the timeout arbitrarily high.  So after setting a timeout, it is good to read back the timeout.

```
ioctl(fd, WDIOC_GETTIMEOUT, &timeout);   /* Update timeout with driver value. */
```

Now, the re-read timeout can be used as a kick frequency.

```
assert(timeout > 2);
while (1) {
  ioctl(fd, WDIOC_KEEPALIVE, 0);
  sleep(timeout-2);
}
```

You can write your own kicking routine in a script/shell command,

```
    while [ 1 ] ; do sleep 1; echo V > /dev/watchdog; done
```

However, the [userspace watchdog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) program is usually used.  This should take care of all the esoteric features.  You can `nice` the user space program to a minimum priority and then the system will reset if user space becomes *hung up*.  **BusyBox** includes a *watchdog* applet.

Each watchdog driver has [separate module parameters](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-parameters.txt) and most include a mechanism to set the timeout; use either the kernel command line or module parameter setting mechanism.  However, the infra-structure `ioctl` timeout is more portable if you do not have specific knowledge of your watchdog hardware.  The `ioctl` is probably more *future proof*, in that your hardware may change.

Sample user space code is included in the [Linux samples directory](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/samples/watchdog/).

Comment: Some *watchdog devices* don't support modifying the timeout.  The kernel will try to extend it in these cases by kicking in a timer interrupt.  But this case is a little different as *ISR* lockups will have a smaller threshold than processes.  The main point being, **timeout is an overloaded concept**.  Often different sub-systems have different latency requirements.  Is it ok for a higher priority *soft modem* task to block for 2s?  Is it ok for a GUI task to block for 2s?  Is it ok for a low priority disk defrag to block for 2s?

Comment: I use that WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT flag but. I am not able to set the timeout  period for watchdog. the output for ioctl(fd,WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT,&timeout) is nonzero. So bydefault 10 secs timeout period is set.

Comment: Quite possible.  Some hardware doesn't support changing the *timeout*, as I said.  Sometimes, a boot loader may have activated the watchdog and there is no way to de-activate or change the timeout; but this is hardware specific. Do you have a Linux version and know the name of the watchdog device?  You can extend the timeout by updating the driver to use a *work queue*, etc which will kick the watchdog a little faster than the fixed frequency.