# Not able to set the watchdog timer timeout embedded linux

Tags: arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, busybox, watchdog

I am developing my application for ARM9 based microprocessor using UBUNTU 12.04 and Qt4.8.

I have an implementation of watchdog timer.

I have implemented the watchdog timer as following.

```
int timeout = 30;    /* time in seconds */
int rc = -1;    /* return value */
int fd = -1; /* WDT Timer File Descriptor*/

fd = open(WDT_DEVICE, O_WRONLY));
if(-1 == fd)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Failed to Open Device : " << WDT_DEVICE;
    return -1;
}


if(ioctl(fd,WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT, &timeout) != 0)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Failed to set the timeout interval of : " << timeout;
    return -1;
}


if(ioctl(fd,WDIOC_GETTIMEOUT, &timeout) != 0);
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Failed to Get the timeout interval of : " << timeout;
    return -1;
}
```

Here I am unable to set the timeout interval. So bydefault system watchdog timer timeout 10 seconds are applied.

> ioctl(fd,WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT, &timeout)

returns -1 and failed.

I want to use 30 seconds timeout. how i can do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change watchdog timer in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402865/how-to-change-the-watchdog-timer-in-linux-embedded).  Also, check the permissions of the device.

Comment: Same concern but still i could not be able to set the timeout interval.

Comment: Yes I will have to check the permission issue. Then I come back to you.

Comment: no effect after changing the permission means it is not the problem of privileges.

Comment: I got one way to configure it. It can be configured by changing the watchdog driver module of kernel. There is a macro for that timeout which is set to 10 by default we can change it as per your need.